# 0-1 knapsack TLE

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I was solving 0-1 knapsack problem (src:https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/0-1-knapsack/)
and would like to understand why I got TLE and know how to get rid of TLE .

My solution : (which showed TLE in hard case)

```
int knapsack(vector<int> A , vector<int> B, int weight , int n , vector<vector<int>> &dp ){
    if(weight==0 || n==0){
        // dp[weight][n] = 0;
        return 0 ;
    }
    if(dp[weight][n]!=(-1)){
        return dp[weight][n];
    }
    if(B[n-1]<=weight){
        dp[weight][n] = max( (knapsack(A,B,weight,n-1,dp)) , (A[n-1] + knapsack(A,B,weight-B[n-1],n-1,dp))  );
        return max( (knapsack(A,B,weight,n-1,dp)) , (A[n-1] + knapsack(A,B,weight-B[n-1],n-1,dp))  );
    }
    // if(B[n-1]>weight){
    else{
        dp[weight][n] = knapsack(A,B,weight,n-1,dp);
        return knapsack(A,B,weight,n-1,dp);
    }
    
}

int Solution::solve(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B, int C) {
    int N = A.size();
    // n rows and weights written vertically in columns 
    vector<vector<int>> dp(C+1, vector<int> (N+1,-1));
    return knapsack(A,B,C,N,dp);
}
```

One solution which I found in discussion tab and does not get TLE which is exactly same as my solution :

```
int knapsack(vector<int>& wt, vector<int>& val, int W, int n, vector<vector<int>>& dp)
{
    if(n == 0 || W == 0)
        return 0;
    if(dp[n][W] != -1)
        return dp[n][W];
    
    if(wt[n-1] <= W)
    return dp[n][W] = max(val[n-1] + knapsack(wt, val, W-wt[n-1], n-1, dp), knapsack(wt, val, W, n-1, dp));
    else
    return dp[n][W] = knapsack(wt, val, W, n-1, dp);
}

int Solution::solve(vector<int> &val, vector<int> &wt, int W) 
{
    int n = wt.size();
    vector<vector<int>> dp(n+1 , vector<int> (W+1, -1));
    return knapsack(wt, val, W, n, dp);
}
```

Is it possible that using a bigger variable name caused me a TLE in the hard case ?

Comment: I don't know what a TLE is.

Comment: TLE == Time Limit Error

Answer (score 0):

You do too many recursive calls.

`knapsack` is not a pure function. It has side effect of modifying `dp`, and the compiler is not smart enough to figure out that a second call in the `else` branch

```
    dp[weight][n] = knapsack(A,B,weight,n-1,dp);
    return knapsack(A,B,weight,n-1,dp);
```

is redundant. Help the compiler and optimize it out manually:

```
    dp[weight][n] = knapsack(A,B,weight,n-1,dp);
    return dp[weight][n];
```

or, just as in the other solution

```
    return dp[weight][n] = knapsack(A,B,weight,n-1,dp);
```

Ditto for the `if` branch,

(And no, variable names do not affect performance).